# Non blocking streaming on Flink

Tags: apache-flink

Hi, I'm trying to run a Flink job that it should process incoming data as below. In the process operator right after `keyBy()`, there should be a case that takes too much time according to some property in data. Even though incoming data have different ids (which is used to `keyBy()` the stream), long processing code in process function blocks other incoming data. I mean the entire stream.

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Envelope> processingStream = deviceStream
    .map(e -> (Envelope) e)
    .keyBy((KeySelector<Envelope, String>) value -> value.eventId) // key by scenarios
    .process(new RuleProcessFunction());
```

In `RuleProcessFunction.java`:

```
...
@Override
public void processElement(Envelope value, Context ctx, Collector<Envelope> out) throws Exception {
    //handleEvent(value, ctx, out);
    if (value.getEventId().equals("I")) {
        System.out.println("hello i");
        for (long i = 0; i < 10000000000L; i++) {

        }
    }
    out.collect(value);
}
```

I expect the long-running code block should not block the entire stream. I know there is AsyncFunction for blocking IO situations but I don't know that it's correct solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't pulling data from an external database like Cassandra, I don't think you need to use an AsyncFunction.

What it could be that you are running the flink job with a single parallelism. Try increasing the parallelism so one core isn't responsible for all of the processing as well as receiving data. Granted, there can still be back pressure if you do this. Since if the core responsible for ingesting data from the source is reading in data faster than the core(s) that are running the processFunction Flink's back pressure handling will slow the rate of ingestion.

Comment: Thanks @Jicaar, what if, i use ListenableFuture or CompletableFuture in my ProcessFunction's processElement(..) method with fixed thread pool ExecutionService. would it be reasonable ?

Comment: ListenableFuture should give you what you want. Honestly haven't used CompletableFuture so I don't know the pros/cons between the two. And yes, I think that would be reasonable.

Comment: states (ValueState, MapState), are they thread-safe ? When i use async approach, i would need to access state of process operator, so it is needed to be close for race-condition kind of issues.